# How to define 'func' and 'iter' in map(func, iter) dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Suppose that I have this list of lists

```
M = [[2,4,2,6],[5,7,2,3],[3,43,1,6]]
```

Running

```
print(list(map(lambda i,j,k: (i,j,k), M[0],M[1],M[2])))
```

returns

```
[(2, 5, 3), (4, 7, 43), (2, 2, 1), (6, 3, 6)]
```

**Question:** Is there a way to do this dynamically? That is, to do write something down (preferable in a single line) that does this for any list of n lists? I would like something like

```
X = [[4,2,2], ..., [9,4,1]]
expression(X)
```

that returns

```
[(4, ..., 9), (2, ..., 4), (2, ..., 1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`

**Ex:**

```
M = [[2,4,2,6],[5,7,2,3],[3,43,1,6]]
print(list(zip(*M)))
```

**Output:**

```
[(2, 5, 3), (4, 7, 43), (2, 2, 1), (6, 3, 6)]
```